# Где хранить более 3 миллиардов строк данных?

Tags: python, база-данных, big-data

Хочу сделать сервис для расшифровки md5, разных sha. Конечно нужно хранить очень очень много данных. Одна из программ из этого же разряда использует БД на 3 миллиарда строк.

Как хранить такие данные, вроде, у .csv ограничение в 1 миллион строк. А БД реляционую или нет я даже не знаю, выдержит ли MySql такое количество данных? 
Посоветуйте БД/способ хранение таких больших данных с максимальной производимостью на поиск значения по ключу.

Comment: возможно вам подойдет MongoDB ?

Comment: В принципе, 3 миллиарда строк это много, но не то что бы очень. У нас на работе в Oracle вполне успешно хранился такой объем

Comment: У меня PostgreSQL на VPS'ке с двумя гигами памяти обрабатывал таблицу с 23 миллиардами записей. Это даже близко не big data.

Comment: @Viktorov, спасибо, посмотрю) Копнув дальше увидел, что миллиард записей в БД это не так много)

Comment: @SegeyGornoataev, спасибо, что вселили в меня уверенность. Как думаете, а MySql справится? Т.к я работал пока что только с MySql.

Comment: @ПавелШеметов в чем проблема запустить у себя mysql и вставить пачками туда парочку миллиардов записей и проверить ? :)

Comment: У csv нет ограничения по размеру - это просто формат файла. Другое дело, что с csv как полноценную базу данных проблематично использовать.

Comment: @ПавелШеметов не знаю, я уже много лет стараюсь не трогать MySQL даже трёхметровой палкой.

Comment: имхо тут надо спросить а как будут использоваться эти строки?, какой характер запросов?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ задал очень правильный вопрос. при таких объемах данных есть смысл смоделировать таблицу(ы) таким образом чтобы минимизировать время чтения/обработки. Для этого надо знать как эти таблицы будут использоваться чаще всего...

Comment: Данные будут использоваться на чтение, и только иногда буду записывать новые данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Если данные однородные и работа с ними линейная: [HDF5](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html)
- Если нужна выборка, *SQL. (У меня PostgreSQL с 8858517598 записями в одной таблице справляется. На SSD.)
- Если их нужно загружать в память полностью, то [Pickle](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-pickle.html). По моим тестам namedtuple был самым быстрым.